# adding jpanel onto website without using applet

Tags: java, swing, java-web-start

How would I be able to share my jframe or jpanel on a website without having to extend from a applet?

I want to be share my java gui program with other people without having them have java or download a zip file for them to run it.

I read online that using an applet is insecure and outdated. Other responses insisted in learning javascript. However, I want to stick with java. I also read about using Java Web Start but it is quite confusing for me. May someone give me a general gist or even a starting point for me to research on this topic.

Comment: Short answer, you can't; Long answer, you can make use of Java Web Start technologies. Longer answer, you can also deploy your app with it's own, embedded JRE and using a native starter (ie exe) start your application using your embedded JRE

Comment: Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file